# Migrating from Eclipse to IntelliJ - Moving a project linked with EGit

Tags: java, eclipse, git, intellij-idea, egit

I have several projects linked to bitbucket repositories using EGit. If I use IntelliJ IDEA for development instead, is there anything I need to keep in mind when migrating the projects over, and keeping them on that repository and updated with IntelliJ's git integration?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [IntelliJ-git integration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-git-integration.html) requires a git, make sure you have the latest (1.8.3+) installed.

Otherwise, you should be able to use the same working tree/repo as the one used by Eclipse Egit. No special migration should be required.